# What the tags <meta , <link rel , and <link href does?

Tags: html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<meta property='og:site_name' content='Blank Title' />
<meta property='og:title' content='Blank Title' />
<meta property='og:description' content='Web Hosting by iPage' />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//assets.dragndropbuilder.com/css/sites.css?buildTime=1407791093" type="text/css" /><link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://www.dragndropbuilder.com/editor/libraries/fancybox/fancybox.css?1407791093' />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<title>Sample HTML5 index.html from MyThinkPond</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Sample HTML5 index.html from MyThinkPond.wordpress.com</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I read that meta tags are for data information. Is that mean they are not doing anything ?
What does link rel do ? And what's the difference between link href and link rel ?
And why i don't see the link href when i'm browsing to this page ?

The only thing i see is: "Sample HTML5 index.html from MyThinkPond.wordpress.com"

Tried to read about it but not quite understand what this tags doing and how they are effecting ?

Comment: They do what the documentation says they do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `rel` attribute specifies the relationship between the current document and the linked document and can be on of the values `alternate`,`archives`,`author`,`bookmark`,`external`,`first`,`help`,`icon`,`last`,`license`,`next`,`nofollow`,`noreferrer`,`pingback`,`prefetch`,`prev`,`search`,`sidebar`,`stylesheet`,`tag`,`up`
and the `href` specifies the location of the linked document
more information http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp